# .gitignore for all except Jenkins job config files

Tags: git, jenkins, gitignore

I'm using this `.gitignore` in the Jenkins directory:

```
#Ignore everything
*
#Don't ignore directories
!*/
#Don't ignore these files
!/.gitignore
!jobs/*/config.xml
!jobs/**/modules**/config.xml
```

But .gitignore files in subfolders aren't ignored. I want to except only the root .gitignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!/.gitignore` tells to ignore the file in your system root.

You probably mean `!./.gitignore`, the one in your Jenkins root.

> But .gitignore files in subfolders aren't ignored. I want to except
>   only the root .gitignore.

First you say they are not ignored, then that you don't want to ignore them? My guess is that you meant to only ignore the `.gitignore` in your Jenkins root directory, but didn't manage. In that case, try the above (`!./.gitignore`).

Comment: How about `!./.gitignore`?

Comment: `!./.gitignore` works great so `./` is needed (using Git 2.3.1).

Do you want to edit your answers so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. That's what I was trying to write, actually, but I had a typo :/

Comment: This is incorrect.  A leading slash in .gitignore is the root of the path name relative to the repository.  See PATTERN FORMAT https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore